# ajax button click not proper

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying ajax for the first time. I have a button in php

```
<input type ="button" name = "save" value = "save"/>
```

I have the following code

```
<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.js">
$(document).ready(function(){$("#save").click(function(){alert("1");})})
</script>
```

I am just trying to make sure that the alert will be displayed before I write any complex  code for implementing ajax call. But the alert is not displayed.
What am I missing? Can anyone please point out.
Thanks in advance
Pre

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<input type ="button" name = "save" id="save" value = "save"/>
```

Comment: <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.js">
$(document).ready(function(){ alert('1'); $("#save").click(function(){alert("2");})})
</script>

Comment: I put in one more alert just to make sure that things are ok, both the alerts are not being displayed

Comment: There is an additional step (separating the script element) as Quentin wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have the id set in the element. the # selector will look for the element with  as the id.

I have demo'ed this in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/EkK69/)

*I put in the e.preventDefault(); because that will stop the page from posting...which is probably not what you want to do if you are going to be doing an AJAX post.*

Comment: <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.js">
$(document).ready(function(){ alert('1'); $("#save").click(function(){alert("2");})})
</script>                                I put in one more alert just to make sure that things are ok, both the alerts are not being displayed

Comment: You have to seperate your jquery include from your actual javascript...try    <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.js"></script>  <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ alert('1'); $("#save").click(function(){alert("2");})}) </script>

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

The content of a script element is used if the browser doesn't understand the `src` attribute or if there is no src attribute.

If you want an inline script and an external script, then you need **two script elements**.

**Second:**

The selector `#save` means "An element with the **id** save". Your input doesn't have an id at all.

Corrected code:

```
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#save").click(function(){
    alert("1");
  });
});
</script>
```